# Jackson failed to convert request element

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, slack, slack-api

I'm using Spring to craft a REST API which exposes a POST endpoint. I'm able to reach the endpoint, but I'm having trouble reading the request body.

The following code works: `payload` contains the object sent.

```
@RestController
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity endpoint(@RequestParam("payload") String str) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Payload payload = objectMapper.readValue(str, Payload.class);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }

}
```

However, the following code DOES NOT works: it throws an exception.

```
@RestController
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity endpoint(@RequestParam("payload") Payload payload) throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }

}
```

The exception:

```
Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'beans.Payload'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'beans.Payload': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Why the latter doesn't work? I thought Spring decode request parameters in the same way...

---

UPDATE: my Payload class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Payload {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("callback_id")
    private String callbackId;

    @JsonProperty("message_ts")
    private String message_ts;

    @JsonProperty("response_url")
    private String responseUrl;

    protected Payload() {}

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getCallbackId() {
        return callbackId;
    }

    public String getMessage_ts() {
        return message_ts;
    }

    public String getResponseUrl() {
        return responseUrl;
    }

}
```

---

UPDATE: I'm testing the endpoint with Postman. This is what I'm sending:

```
KEY       VALUE
payload   { "type": "test" }
```

and this is the error I got:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-28T10:38:33.133+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------586093407866564427326096;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this endpoint? and what is Payload class?

Comment: I'm not directly calling it: this endpoint is for a Slack Bot, so I'm "calling" it by pressing a button in the Bot's response. The Payload class is a a class of mine - more in the updated question - which contains the following fields: https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide#action_payload

Answer (score 0):

Payload constructor should not be protected. It should be public.

Change it to

```
Public PayLoad(){}
```

Otherwise, controllers cant create a payload object when mapping is done.

Comment: Use "public Payload" you have taken it as a single word while class naming

Comment: Done, but got the same `Failed to convert request element` error

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) instead of `@RequestParam`. Your `Payload` is in post body and `@RequestBody` annotation will deserialize it to payload.

Comment: Done, but now the endpoint is not reached (no exceptions, just not reached).

Comment: When you have `@RequestMapping` without HTTP method specified, Spring uses the same mapping for handling all HTTP methods. How do you know you are serving GET or POST? You can [enable logging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) to find out more about  incoming request. Then update the question with that information.

Comment: Tested with Postman, you can see the error I got in updated question.

Comment: Your rest controller endpoint has path: `/endpoint`, postman error says `/test`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just get rid of `protected Payload() {}` . As you don't have any parameterized constructer you are fine, Java compiler will take care of adding the default constructer to the compiled byte code.
2. And you need to change this

Controller method

```
@RestController
public class RestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity endpoint(@RequestParam("payload") Payload payload) throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}
```

## Changes

a. Change HTTP request method to `POST` it, instead of `GET` . (`method = RequestMethod.POST`) .

b. Change Payload to a message body insteda of request param (`@RequestParam("payload") Payload payload` --> `@RequestBody Payload payload` ).

Change it as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity endpoint(@RequestBody Payload payload) throws IOException {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

Comment: Getting read of the protected constructor rise the following exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `beans.Payload` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

Comment: Made the other change you wrote, but now the endpoint is not reached (no exceptions, just not reached).

Comment: This endpoint is for a Slack Bot, so I'm testing it by pressing a button in the Bot's response.

Comment: How do you know whether slack bot is using GET or POST.. My opinion, one baby step at a time, make this working, test it using a basic tooling like postman or curl, then go explore other fancy clients like a bot.. multiple variables in play will make a problem difficult to solve.

Comment: Tested with Postman, you can see the error I got in updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL patterns are mal-configured. Try,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class PayLoadController {

@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity endpoint(@RequestBody Payload payload) throws IOException {
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}}
```

Just copy paste this code and rename controller file name.
Then post your data to,
localhost:8080/endpoint/

Comment: Also rename your controller for a name other than "RestController". Rename it to "PayLoadController" .

Comment: While posting by postman,  checkout the radio button of "raw" then select "application/json" from appeared drop down. Then type the json object with all fields inside "{}" . Then post